# Animating JSON models without three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I know that we can load JSON models in WebGL, but I don't know how to animate them if we have a rigged model loaded. Is there any way of doing this without three.js?

Comment: Just for clarification: You can not load JSON models in WebGL. WebGL is just a low-level rasterization library. Anything relating to models or animation is either code you wrote or a library you used and is not WebGL. For example Three.js, as you mentioned, loads JSON models and generates shaders and handles a matrix hierarchy and animation etc. All of that is Three.js though not WebGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate a rigged model using THREE.js (however you seem to not want to use the built in functionality).

What THREE.js is doing in the background, is passing all the matrix transforms (an array of matrices), and per vertex it passes the bone indexes (up to 4) and bone weights to the vertex shader. In the vertex shader, it's blending between those matrices based on vertex weight and translating the vertex. So in theory you can pass values to the vertex shader to animate things. Or just use THREE.js animation routines.

It can use 2 methods to store all this data. One method uses an "image texture" which stores all those matrix and does some fancy footwork to turn the image into matrices in the vertex shader. Another method is just passing uniform matrix array (for newer graphics cards this is preferred method).